# How to display a File Archive with SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to display a directory on my website with files and subdirectories. I can't find any examples.

Does anyone know how to list all files and directories?

Comment: Directory of Server where you have published your code, are trying to build ftp client?

Comment: Yes i want to list a dir from the asset folder recursive with links for downloading the files and open the subdirs etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can create an `AssetListingPage` page that can loop through the content of the assets directory and display all folders and file links.

In the `AssetListingPage` controller we have a `RootAssets` function that will return a list of the files and folders in the assets directory.

**AssetListingPage.php**

```
class AssetListingPage extends Page {
}

class AssetListingPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function RootAssets() {
        return File::get()->filter('ParentID', 0);
    }

}
```

We add a layout template for `AssetListingPage` that loops through the `RootAssets`.

**templates/Layout/AssetListingPage.ss**

```
<div class="content-container">

    <h1>$Title</h1>

    $Content

    <% if $RootAssets %>
    <ul>
        <% loop $RootAssets %>
        <% include AssetList %>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
    <% end_if %>

</div>
```

We add an include template `AssetList` to recursively list the folder or file and list any children.

**templates/Includes/AssetList.ss**

```
<li class="$ClassName">
<% if $ClassName == 'Folder' %>
    $Title
    <% if $Children %>
    <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
        <% include AssetList %>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
    <% end_if %>
<% else %>
    <a href="$Link">$Name</a>
<% end_if %>
</li>
```